# How to clear the specific <td> data of <table> tag using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tapshil" id="" border="2px" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th> <font face="preeti">l;=g+=</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> k|=b=g</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> ldlt</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> eG;f/ dx;'n tyf hl/jfgf</font> </th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> cGtMz'Ns</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> d"=c=s/ </font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> hDdf dx;'n</font> </th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> hDdf  </font> </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <!-- put loop here -->
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>11   
            1212231
         </td>
         <td id="nameOfPeople">Arun Lama  2070-01-01 2072-01-01 Amin Shrestha  2070-01-01 2072-01-01
         </td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>7</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td id="totalOfAll">36</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>


</html>
```

I have a  `<td id="nameOfPeople"></td>`.I want to clear the data of this specific  by using its Id. So i tried to clear the data but it is not being cleared. I have tried as :

```
$(".tapshil tbody tr td .nameOfPeople").text('');
```

I tried to empty the data of  but it is not clearing the field.how to make it empty?

Comment: `$("#nameOfPeople").text('')` - note the `#` used for `id`s

Comment: `.` means class `#` means id.

Comment: If you're likely to have more than one row, then don't use `id=` (as per comments on your other question) - change to `<td class='nameOfPeople'` and then your selector with `.` will work, but will find the `td` across all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id must be unique in that table

```
$("#nameOfPeople").text('');
```

Comment: thank you worked fyn plz upvote my question new to SO :)

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect to happen in it's place? The table can't reflow to fill the space left - this seems like a recipe for buggy browser responses.

Think about hiding the contents of the td, not the td itself.

You can use inline css to hide it :)

`<td style="visibility:hidden"> Your content is hidden </td>`

You can hide it via JQuery also.
Use $("#td_id").hide();

Comment: `$("#id").text()` clears the *content* of the td, not the td itself.  Nowhere in the question does it suggest that OP wants to hide the cell, only the content ("data").